# Socket Programming ConnectException

Tags: java, sockets, connectexception

Im trying a [socket](/questions/tagged/socket) programming to build an app to send and receive messages it also uses [cryptography](/questions/tagged/cryptography) everything is set and working except that the Connect Exception: it is constantly saying connection timed out...
i have this code on working

```
socket s = new socket(destination,8888);
```

then furthur using the outputstream
at firstly initiating end and then

```
socket d= new socket (sender,8888);
```

and then input stream
at the receiving end 
and both system are well connect with the code

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(8888);
Socket b= new Socket();
b=ss.accept();
```

what could possibly be wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alot of chat programs spawn a new Thread, when the connection has been made, have you considered that? if you just do

```
   ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(8888);
   Socket b= new Socket();
   b=ss.accept();
```

And you program ends after this line, it could cause a timeout exception because
the client instantly lost the connection, when the server closed down.

if this is completely retarded, please provide more code, its hard to make assumptions about your implementation.

Comment: its a very big code ... @DenLilleMand i can only say that the code about [tag:Serversocket] is just starting of the program..we are using the pipeline [tag:Serversocket] successfully